# My iMac not responding to any macOS key

Tags: macos, bootcamp, imac

I have install Windows 10 on my 21" iMac 2015 with Boot Camp which change my hard iMac hard disk file type, since then I am trying to access macOS on my machine but no luck, I tried everything but my system auto going to Windows.

So I tired to remove Windows from my hard disk and by formatting whole disk from Windows repair tool on startup and now I am even not able to access Windows and my iMac just showing a white folder with "?" mark in it.

I tried Target Disk Mode but no command is working on startup.

It seems like macOS BIOS system is wipeout from my iMac.

Please help me out.

Comment: Do you have a Time Machine backup?

Comment: Have you tried Recovery?  Boot while holding `Command R`

Comment: Yes i have tried Command R but imac not responding to any command.

Comment: No i do not have Time Machine backup but i do not care about back files i just want a fresh reinstall with clean memory...